# write linked list and make another one with reverse numbers of first list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

So I can make the first linked list, and then I can store all numbers in an array with a size of numbers and then put them all in second linked list as I want, but is there any good algorithm to do that without array?

TY!

Comment: You can make the second linked list directly from the first, and it will be in reverse order, because a single-linked list is a LIFO stack.

Comment: You should not be using an array with a linked-list. They are two separate and distinct data structures. Rather than make a second list with reverse numbers, just create a *Doubly-Linked* list that will allow traversal in both the forward and reverse directions -- problem solved.

Comment: I thought about it, but anyway hoped on some mystery algorism)

Comment: There is no mystery. Traverse the first list from its head, and insert each item into the head of a new list. No array is needed, you are possibly over-thinking it.

Comment: @Weather Vane sorry sir, should I use recursion then?

Comment: No, plain iteration using the link as the control. If you want to keep *both* lists, you'll have to allocate memory for the duplicated nodes (or provide *two* links which then becomes the doubly-linked list mentioned by David).

Comment: @Weather Vane OOO o figure it out, there is a thing called stack, first come last out. TY sIR

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, Sir! I posted my program but I think it's too big)

Comment: You may benefit from [Doubly-Linked List of Integers - Remove Rand Nodes Check](https://pastebin.com/E6WpPjTC) which provides examples of list creation, traversal, and node removal in random order until empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
//HERE WE GO!

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct listNode{
int value;
struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;

void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, int value);
void copy(ListNodePtr *sPtr, int value);

void printList(ListNodePtr sPtr);
int main()
{
int value;

    ListNodePtr startPtr=0;
    ListNodePtr secondPtr=0;
    int tempValue;

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    value=rand()%15;
    insert(&startPtr,value);

    }
    while(startPtr!=0){
    tempValue=startPtr->value;
    copy(&secondPtr,tempValue);
    startPtr=startPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    printList(secondPtr);

}

void copy(ListNodePtr *sPtr, int value)
{
    ListNodePtr newPtr;
    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

if(newPtr!=0){
    newPtr->value=value;
    newPtr->nextPtr=*sPtr;
    *sPtr=newPtr;   
    }else{
    printf("%d not inserted. No memory", value);
    }
}

void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr,int value)
{
ListNodePtr newPtr,currentPtr,previousPtr;

newPtr=malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
if(newPtr!=0){
    newPtr->value=value;
    newPtr->nextPtr=0;

currentPtr=*sPtr;
previousPtr=0;

while(currentPtr!=0&&value>currentPtr->value){
    previousPtr=currentPtr;
    currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
if(previousPtr==0){
    newPtr->nextPtr=*sPtr;
    *sPtr=newPtr;
    }else{
    previousPtr->nextPtr=newPtr;
    newPtr->nextPtr=currentPtr;
    }
    }else{
    printf("%d not inserted. No memory available");
    }
}   

void printList(ListNodePtr sPtr)
{
while(sPtr!=0){
printf("%d -->",sPtr->value);
sPtr=sPtr->nextPtr;
}
}
```